# SQL: How to do column operation on existing tables in database and create new table from it?

Tags: sql-server, table

I am fairly new to SQL so may not be using correct terminology for my question.

- I have got test data in database identified by part number in a "partNo" column.
- Each row of the "partNo" column has a specific part number, say "part.20".
- Another row in this table identifies sub-parts within the main part number part.20 as part.20.01, part20.02. part20.03 and so on, which get measured.
- Other columns in each test data table for a given partNo contains measured data on sub-parts.
- Every test data table corresponding to a "partNo" has a column "Fail Category" with different row entries with different entries for "fail category" bins.
- Example of fail category bin could be "flat",  "hard", "long" etc.

I want to do a column operation in a table for each "partNo" to add all entries with specific bin, say "flat" and then divide by number of rows i.e number of sub-parts (and then multiply by 100) to give me "percentage_flat_Fail" for a specific "partNo". This I want to do for all available part numbers in the database.

I then want to create a new two column table with all available part numbers in one column and corresponding percentage_flat_Fail values in another column.

How to I get started building my SQL query (unfortunately I cannot share real examples unless I modify them drastically)?

Comment: *Examples are worth 1,000 words...* If you could please provide the `CREATE TABLE` definition statement for your Tables, some example data (in a tabular format), and example output of the data that you want to achieve, that'll help us a ton with helping you

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: Without sample data and expected results it's impossible for us to help. You can anonymize it, and we only need a handful of rows showing all edge cases.